# Converting a for loop from Batch to Git Bash

Tags: bash, batch-file, git-bash

I've been stuck on a particular for loop in a Windows script and I can't find any help on how to translate it to its git Bash equivalent. The code is here:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2" %%i IN (`tasklist /v ^| findstr /c:"IRCam_Data_Collector"`) DO taskkill /pid %%i
```

if I change it to the standard shell, it gives out an error

> syntax error near unexpected token `"tokens=2 delims=,"'

my version of converted shell code:

```
for //f "tokens=2 delims=," %i in (`tasklist //v | findstr //c:"IRCam_Data_Collector"`); do taskkill //pid %i; done
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Yes, I know that Git Bash is different from bash. I figured out that it has to do something with the exploded variable iteration "For /f". Since I have no experience with Git Bash, thus I asked for the help

Comment: (Git) Bash is *very* different from Batch.  You can't just change a few characters and expect it to work.

Comment: yes, I know that. I figured out that it has to do something with the exploded variable iteration "For /f". Since I have no experience with Git Bash, thus I asked for the help

Comment: Standard bash doesn't even have such a thing as `tasklisk` or `findstr` or `taskkill` (though if there are Windows-native executables in the PATH of your interpreter, they may be usable even so). It would do a lot of good to decompose this, breaking it down into small pieces and testing whether each individual one works; otherwise, someone would need to have their own Windows machine to be able to answer this or test the correctness of someone else's answer.

Comment: I am really sorry for the hassle. I am very new with the windows bash and batch things. This is not my mojo at all but however due to some limitations in SIEMENS IPC i had to use Windows rather than Linux and need this script to terminate my python scripts when there is an update in the git repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve what you expected :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for pid in $(tasklist //v | awk '/IRCam_Data_Collector/{print $2}'); do
    echo taskkill //F //pid $pid
done
```

Remove `echo` once you see it does what you wanted.

Comment: Why `//v`? Forward slashes don't need to be doubled up, and the OP's original batch code didn't do so.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You can see in his `bash` attempt, // is everywhere. Without double slash, git-bash will try to take it as windows directory.

Comment: Ahh! Forgot about msys-isms; I'd assumed the OP was thinking about backslashes and doubling them up in error.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My answer did basically what you suggested in your comment to his post. We need to be more tolerant towards beginers and encourage them to learn new things (like bash).

Comment: Thanks for the assist but for some reason, it is not returning any echo. I also tried running tasklist //v | awk '/^IRCam_Data_Collector/{print $2}' separately but that returned nothing although i have two windows opened with that name. Also be noted that the widow name awk should belike *IRCam_Data_Collector.... a wildcard at the starting

Comment: If you do `tasklist //v`, can you see `IRCam_Data_Collector` as the first element of a line. Try to run `tasklist //v | awk '/IRCam_Data_Collector/{print $2}'` (with ^ removed)

Comment: yes removing the ^ works... thanks a lot.... could you please explain me the case of the ^sign?

Comment: ^ makes it match at the beginning of the line. I thought IRCam_Data_Collector is the name of your executable. Answer updated.